# Is multiple URL fetch using the same URL object possible

Tags: java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;


public class URLConnectionReader {


    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP"; 
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "password";



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{


Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


URL o = new URL("http://www.worldportsource.com/countries.php");




        URLConnection yc = o.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));






ReadURL ru = new ReadURL();

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt= null;

String[] va0 = new String[200];
String[] va1 = new String[197];

//ReadURL[] ru = new ReadURL[200];


        String inputLine;
    String table="<table";
    String dtable="</table";
    String dtr="</tr>";
    String tr="<tr";
String link="http://www.worldportsource.com";
String endcontent="-- end content --";

String val0 =null;
String val1=null;
String vol0=null;

String td="<td>";
String dtd="</td";



int x=0,x1=0,z=0,s=0,j=0;

inputLine = in.readLine();
String inputLine2 = null;





 try{

      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

   }
catch(SQLException se){se.printStackTrace();}//Handle errors for JDBC
catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}//Handle errors for Class.forName






do
{
if(inputLine.indexOf("- end content -")!=-1)
z++;



if(z<1){

if(inputLine.indexOf("- start content -")!=-1)
{x++;}

if(x>=3)
{

if(inputLine.indexOf("<tr")!=-1)
s++;


if(s>=2){


if(inputLine.indexOf("php\">")!=-1){
val0=(inputLine.substring(inputLine.indexOf("php\">")+5,inputLine.indexOf("</a>")));


if(inputLine.indexOf("a href=")!=-1){
val1=link+(inputLine.substring(inputLine.indexOf("a href=\"")+8,inputLine.lastIndexOf("\">")));
j++;
va0[j]=val0;
va1[j]=val1;








}}




}
}


}//z if
}while((inputLine = in.readLine())!= null);




ru.sendURL(va1);


      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){}
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }




  in.close();
    }
}


class ReadURL{

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       String[] al=null;
int p=1;
URL o1= null;
Scanner sc2=null;



public void sendURL(String []t) throws Exception
{
al=t;
System.out.println(""+al[p]);

for(p=1;p<t.length;p++)
getURL(al[p]);

}



public void getURL(String t) throws Exception
             {



String[] vol = new String[200];


String country=null;
String inputLine;
int x1=0,i=0,b=0,z1=0,table=0;






o1 = new URL(t);
sc2 = new Scanner(o1.openStream());

inputLine= sc2.nextLine();



while((inputLine = sc2.nextLine())!=null) {


if(inputLine.indexOf("<div")!=-1)
table++;
if(table==12)
{

country = (inputLine.substring(inputLine.lastIndexOf("php\">")+5,inputLine.lastIndexOf("</a")));
table++;

}











if(inputLine.indexOf("- end content -")!=-1)
z1++;



if(z1<1){




if(inputLine.indexOf("- start content -")!=-1)
{x1++;}

if(x1>=3)
{
if(inputLine.indexOf("<table")!=-1)
b++;

if(b>=1){

if(inputLine.indexOf("php\">")!=-1){



vol[i]=(inputLine.substring(inputLine.indexOf("php\">")+5,inputLine.indexOf("</a")));
System.out.println(""+country+"\t"+vol[i]);
i++;
}//("php\"")
}//(x1>=2)
}//ifb>1
}//endcontent
}//while

}//method close

}//clas
```

A string array is passed to the sendURL() the string has 196 links
getURl is suppose to take each link and parse it and return the port names of each link.
But it does it only for the 1st link which is passed.
i.e i get portname only for 1 country link..
i want portnames from all the links displayed

Comment: Please post here the result that you get.

Comment: This code doesn't compile, and therefore doesn't fetch any links at all, but when you make it compile and execute it should fetch all of them. I don't see any evidence here that it doesn't.

Comment: Not this code. See @neomega's answer. You have two `o1`s, which won't compile. Copy and paste your *real* code.

Comment: Hi everyone..The original code is posted .
worldportsource.com/countries.php this link has 196 countries and also has link for each country(i am passing all the 196 links as String array to that method)Each link has port names of the corresponding country.. My goal is to print all the port names(il save in Database later) of all the 196 countries.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile and you will hit an ArrayOutOfBoundException at `myArray[3]="http://www.worldportsource.com/ports/index/IND.php";`

- You are creating the same reference name o1 2 times in the same scope.
- You are creating an array which can store 3 objects and you put 4 objects in it.

To answer your title, you are not using the same URL object because your are calling new URL(myUrl) multiple times -> each new means a new object is created

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this code compiles. You have duplicate declaration of variable "o1". Also you will hit a run time exception as you are trying to assign myArray[3] when myArray is only of size 3. Your logic is creating new URL object each time in the loop, so there should not be any problem there. You have to close the streams you have opened towards then end of that loop if you are not doing it already.

If you are executing the program from command line, most probably you are executing the last successful compiled class file.